# Accent-insensitive search in com_search

Tags: search

I just came across a special requirement - using the com_search and the Joomla search module. Currently I am getting results that are different if the search keyword contains accents or not.

So "καλημέρα"(accented) vs "καλημερα"(no accent) are treated differently.

Anyone knows what is the current case with the com_search in Joomla and how I could get the same search results disregarding if I used accents or not?

Searching a bit in Google, I came this old post, it seems that there was some talking about this... but what is the current status?
https://developer.joomla.org/joomlacode-archive/issue-30954.html

Answer (score 1):

It was committed in 2013 to 3.x.  So if you're running 2.5 or 1.5, this wasn't changed.

Comment: Hi Michael... so this is something that should work by default in J3? Is there a setting that I m missing somewhere that enables this? as I don't get  accent-insensitive search on this particular site (j3). I should check it on a clean install as well...